# Should I use a pronoun after each conjunction in this if statement?

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjunctions

Should I use a pronoun after each conjunction in this if statement?

> If I look at the floor and think that you all have to pay for every
> moment of my life and become upset that why no one cares about me.

Comment: The sentence doesn't actually make sense.  Sorry.  I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to say here. There are missing words at the end. Perhaps "If I look at the floor, and think that others have to pay for every moment of my life, then that is why I become upset thinking that no one cares about me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to repeat a pronoun in a simple coordination:

> I played tennis and read a book.

But it might be required in various subordinate constructions

> I drank water because *I* was thirsty.  (the pronoun can't be omitted)

It can also clarify a sentence with several clauses.

> I thought that you passed the test and I celebrated.  (omitting "I"  might be create ambiguity as it could be "... and you celebrated")

This is the case in your sentence.  It is hard to understand because I don't know if you mean "... and if I become upset..." or " ... you all have to pay for every moment of my life and you all become upset".

The last part may be missing some words. You probably mean "then that is because" instead of "that why" and the overall meaning is strange (there is no natural link between "no one cares" and "think you all have to pay")